# Download file from VM 'pyvmomi'

Tags: python, virtual-machine, pyvmomi

I'm having difficulty downloading file from VM using 'InitiateFileTransferFromGuest' in python. Here's the code:

```
def main8(host,user,password,
```

VM_NAME,VM_USER,VM_PASS,LOCAL_FILE_PATH,REMOTE_FILE_PATH,UUID):

```
class Namespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

args = Namespace(host=host,user=user,password=password,
    disable_ssl_verification=True,port=443,
    find = None,REMOTE_FILE_PATH=REMOTE_FILE_PATH,
    VM_NAME=VM_NAME,VM_USER=VM_USER,VM_PASS=VM_PASS,
    LOCAL_FILE_PATH=LOCAL_FILE_PATH,UUID=UUID)

vm_path = args.REMOTE_FILE_PATH
try:
    si = service_instance.connect(args)
    content = si.RetrieveContent()

    vm = None
    if args.UUID:
        search_index = si.content.searchIndex
        vm = search_index.FindByUuid(None, args.UUID, True)
    elif args.VM_NAME:
        content = si.RetrieveContent()
        vm = pchelper.get_obj(content, [vim.VirtualMachine], args.VM_NAME)

    if not vm:
        raise SystemExit("Unable to locate VirtualMachine.")

    print("Found: {0}".format(vm.name))

    tools_status = vm.guest.toolsStatus
    if (tools_status == 'toolsNotInstalled' or
            tools_status == 'toolsNotRunning'):
        raise SystemExit(
            "VMwareTools is either not running or not installed. "
            "Rerun the script after verifying that VMWareTools "
            "is running")

    creds = vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication(username=args.VM_USER, password=args.VM_PASS)

 
    try:
        src="C:\\remote\\1.txt" #Server's directory
        fti = content.guestOperationsManager.fileManager.InitiateFileTransferFromGuest(vm, creds, src)
        print(fti.url)
        dest="C:\\local\\1.txt"
        resp=requests.get(fti.url, verify=False)
        with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(resp.content)
    except IOError as ex:
            print('error :::',ex)
except vmodl.MethodFault as error:
     print("Caught vmodl fault  :::: " + error.msg)
```

the log output is as the following:

```
vm:::::::::output--Found: Win10 X64 4*4*50
"error ::: URL has an invalid label."
```

thanks for helping